# Show products with zero price at the end

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a WordPress/WooCommerce site, which displays products sorted by price ascending using the default WooCommerce loop. Some products have zero price, and should be shown at the end.

Also there is the plugin installed which adds a meta field for zero-price message.

Is there a way to show the products which have this meta field at the end? Or, sort them so that the products which price is not specified, would display after other ones?

Now I am trying to get it work by the following code:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'custom_order', 10, 2 );
function custom_order( $orderby ){
    global $wpdb;
    if( ! is_admin() && is_product_category() ) :
        $orderby = "CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value >= 0 THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC ELSE ''";
    endif;


    return $orderby;
}
```

I am not understand SQL and when I use this I am getting 404 error. Is there a way to fix it, or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL convention calls for the word `END` to close out a `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_value >= 0 THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC ELSE '' END
```